# How to estimate the pose of a object from the quaternion?

Tags: quaternions, euler-angles

I have a quaternion which contains q0,q1,q2,q3 from this I need to estimate the pose of a object at a particular time t, could you please let me know how it can be done.

quaternion(0.873117209569405, -2.27209068414177, -1.03476871647304, -0.443864988118011).

What can be inferred from this?

Comment: I guess, you ken Slerp from indentity quaternion to the given one .

Comment: Thanks for the reply, could you please explain me bit clearly. Not able to understand it

Comment: start from here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp

and try to find "slerp" in math library that you are using.